# find a generator for the group $G =\{ f(x) = x+n\mid n\in \Bbb Z \}$ with the group operation being composition.

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Another question from 'A book of Abstract Algebra' by Pinter.

For each $n\in \Bbb Z$ define $f_n = x+n$. Then $f_n\in S_{\Bbb R}$, the symmetric set on $\Bbb R$. The group operation being composition. Now $f_n \circ f_m =f_{m+n}$ and $f^{-1}_n=f_{-n}$

Let $G=\{ f_n \mid n\in \Bbb Z \}$ such that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_{\Bbb R}$. Show that $G$ is cyclic by finding a generator.

I cannot seem to find the right generator. Using $f_1$ as a generator produces all $f_n$ for $n = 1,2,3,\ldots$ but then the identity $f_0$ is not included and the inverses are missing. Similarly for $f_{-1}$. What am I missing? I just need to find the generator but I cannot seem to find it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove $G \cong \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Technically I haven't covered isomorphisms yet. But I would use the bijection $g:\Bbb Z \to G$ where $g(n) = f_n$, thus $G \cong \mathbb Z$. Then since $1$ is a generator for the cyclic group $\Bbb Z$ we know $f_1$ is the generator for the group $G$ which is thus cyclic. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly! The isomorphy preserves such properties, so you are done once you have the isomorphism. To rigorously prove that $g$ is in fact an [isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism), you need to check, that it respects the group operations, i. e. $g(m+n)=g(m)\circ g(n)$ for all $m,n$, which is rather obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Here $f_0$ is the identity map and is included by hypothesis, so your generator $f_1$ is correct.  Here $f_{-1}$ is not missing: it is the inverse of $f_1$!

Comment: I think I understand. So for the generator $f_1$ the group generated is $ \{\ldots f_1^{-2},f_1^{-1},f_1^{0},f_1^{1},f_1^{2},\ldots$ instead of just the positive powers? Thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: Your are welcome!